# Handling GCM at logout

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, logout

I have integrated Google Cloud Messaging.I want that when user logout he should not receive any push notification.For that do i need to unregister the device from receiving push notification at GCM server.Or should it be handled from app's server.What all things related to GCM should I keep in mind or do while logging out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unregister a device from GCM using registration Id in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057413/unregister-a-device-from-gcm-using-registration-id-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can unregister device from your server. As a regeneration id is used to send push, delete that id from your server db.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want user receiving push after sign out. you need to implement a logic on the app server (which send push request to GCM) which you can consume it on the app end while user logs out.

Like if user sign-out delete the corresponding GCM token from the app server.

Comment: what if you're offline when logout; implement something to repeatedly retry even after app reboot?